# How do I set the default font size?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have tried setting the Default Font Size to 12; but every time I open up Word the font size in the box shows 10.

Comment: You ask how to set the default size and then you go on saying that you set the default size. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the file normal.dot or normal.dotx.  Open the file by right clicking and select open.  Do not double click as that will not open the file to make changes.

Once the file is open.  Change the file and save.  Try to open a new document to verify the settings worked.

Comment: Changing the font size like that won't work. You need to modify the "Normal" style to your preferred font size and then save the document template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Word 2007.

Follow the steps to set the Default `Font` + `Font Size` :-

1. Open a new word document
2. On the `Home` Tab, Under `Font` Group
3. Change the `Font Name` OR `Font Size`
4. As per screenshot, Click on **`Step 1`** icon
5. You will see `Font` Popup window
6. Click on `Default` button as shown in screenshot **`Step 2`**
7. Click on `Yes` button as shown in screenshot **`Step 3`**
8. Close the word and reopen the new document
9. Finally you will see your expected font name and font size

Refer the screenshot for more info.

[image: Setting default font name and size]